# Android application - Only audio running on HTML5 video

Tags: android, html, video

Right now, I'm developing mobile application - Simple Web browser with Android Studio 2.3 (Android SDK API 15).

I'm using WebView to display web pages. All renders properly except videos (on YouTube or other platform with HTML5 videos). I can only hear audio but the screen of the video is black and that's it. I tried different solutions:

I enabled hardware acceleration on  in Manifest file:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Also I set this for my Main Activity java file. Brow is my variable for WebView.

```
    brow.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    brow.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    brow.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

And still with no luck. You can see my problem on the screenshot. So I'm waiting for working solution! If you need more info, type comment below! Thanks!
[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnNfA.jpg)